# Removing the unwanted signs in asp.net using Json

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, angularjs

Actually I tried to remove the html unwanted elements in my output such as **`" , '`** etc...

Here is my code used in my script tag

```
scope.categorywithouthtml = function () {
        return sce.trustAsHtml(scope.directories.dirurl);
        return sce.trustAsHtml(scope.directories.text);
    };
```

Here is my code to remove in **dirurl** and **text**

```
<span" ng-bind-html="categorywithouthtml()" "{{dir.dirurl}}"></span>
        <a href= "{{dir.dirurl}}"   class="button1"  rel="{{dir.text}}">
```

I used span to remove it , Did i missed anything.

```
<a href= "{{dir.dirurl}}"   class="button1"  rel="{{dir.text}}">
```

In the place of **{{dir.dirurl}}** the output should not have the **" , . '** etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Code.

```
scope.categorywithouthtml = function () {
return sce.trustAsHtml(scope.directories.dirurl);
};
```

Then just give this code,But one condition is that you can get only one value at a time, Looping values wont work.

```
<span ng-bind-html="categorywithouthtml()"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but I want to point out that your second return statement will never be reached here:

```
scope.categorywithouthtml = function () {
    return sce.trustAsHtml(scope.directories.dirurl);//This exits the function
    return sce.trustAsHtml(scope.directories.text);//This line is never reached
};
```

Comment: if i give the first line alone, then that shuold give the output know, but it is not showing the result